# enable/disable fields for moxy serialization with default being disabled

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, moxy

I have read through numerous posts about custom serialization options using moxy (see [Jaxb marshalling with custom annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501439/jaxb-marshalling-with-custom-annotations) as an example) but I cannot seem to find an easy way to exclude a field by default but include it when some property is set.

For example, if I have a simple POJO with three fields

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person{

   @XmlElement private String email;
   @XmlElement private String fullName;
   @XmlElement private String ssn;

}
```

...and I want to leave ssn out by default when serialized, but include it only when I set a specific marshaller property (or the like). How would I go about doing that?  In other words, disable the field by default, but include it when I explicitly ask for it.  Even if I take the explicit @XmlNamedObjectGraph approach as mentioned in one of the answers in the aforementioned post, I am left with the default option being an object graph with all fields.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify an object graph name when you create the `JAXBContext` it will be set by default on all the `Marshaller` and `Unmarshaller` instances created from it.

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OBJECT_GRAPH, "yourGraphName");
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Foo.class}, properties);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Blaise!  I was hoping that I could enforce the rule through the domain class itself.  I am trying to force the user to make the conscious decision to expose this field when marshalling.  I don't mind enabling this exposure through a property in the context if that is possible, but I really want the default marshalling to not include the field.  Since I won't always control the JAXBContext I can't guarantee they will set it properly.  Is there a way to have the field labeled as @XmlTransient but to remove that designation if an object graph is specified?

Comment: @jmdev - You could have 2 JAXBContexts.  The first with metadata via annotations representing the default behaviour you want.  The second with metadata overridden using MOXy's external mapping document:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html

Comment: Thank you again Blaise!  Per your suggestion I default with the annotations and provide a binding which allows marshalling of the sensitive fields.