# JAX-RS - how to get multiple representations/projections of resource?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaxb, jax-rs, projection, jaxb2

**Scenario:**

- It's a REST API using plain JavaEE 7
- There's a `Person` entity
- `GET /persons` returns a list of all persons
- `GET /persons/{id}` returns a single person

**Now I'd like those API endpoints to return different representations of the entity:**

- `/persons` should return only `id`, `firstName`, `lastName`
- `/persons/{id}` should return all fields

What I already thought about:

- **The DTO approach:** Create a `PersonSummary` class with only `id`, `firstName` and `lastName` fields. Then using Dozer (or some other mapper) to copy the fields from `Person -> PersonSummary`. And then returning the `PersonSummary` object list.
- **Using `javax.json.Json`:** Manually assemble the object to return. But that way I only get JSON, no more XML `:(`
- **XML schema files:** (Don't know if this actually could work) Write a `.xsd` file for every representationand let Jaxb process the resulting representation.

What I've seen so far:

- In Spring you can simply create an `interface` with all getters, that should be included. (like here ( https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/21/what-s-new-in-spring-data-dijkstra ) at the bottom).
- With Jackson, you can use `@JsonView` for that ( http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews ).
- Using MOXy there is `@XmlNamedObjectGraphs`( https://stackoverflow.com/a/19526044/1321564 ).

---

Is there a (simple) way to do this with JavaEE? Or is there some nice external library for that?

---

### EDIT: Runtime annotation manipulation

What do you think about this idea (This is basically just like `@JsonView` from Jackson):

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyClass {
  @MyViewAnnotation @MyOtherViewAnnotation
  String s1;

  String s2;

  @MyViewAnnotation
  String s3;
}
```

What to do with that? (pseudo code)

```
// resource object comes from some JAX-RS interceptor along
// with the preferred view annotation (in this case @MyViewAnnotation)

Annotation viewAnnotation = @MyViewAnnotation;

for(Field f : resource) {
  if(f.hasAnnotation(viewAnnotation)) {
    f.addAnnotation(@XmlElement);
  } else {
    f.addAnnotation(@XmlTransient);
  }
}

// return manipulated resource object back to JAX-RS
```

Expected results:

1. When passing `@MyViewAnnotation`, it will generate `@XmlElement String s1` and `@XmlElement String s2`. `s3` will be `@XmlTransient`.
2. When passing `@MyOtherViewAnnotation`, it will generate `@XmlElement` on `s1`. `s2` and `s3` will be `@XmlTransient`.

I don't know if it's possible to intercept JAX-RS processing in the right place to create a modified class and then pass that class to the normal JAX-RS processing. But that way, it could be easily done and JAX-RS could generate JSON and XML the same way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of in JAX-RS to support this behavior is to use a custom `MessageBodyWriter` with a special content type, e.g. `application/json+list` vs `application/json+details`.  Then in your `MessageBodyWriter` serialize only those specific fields.

The Jackson views approach seems to be the one best suited for your need though, assuming you use the Jackson JAX-RS provider.  You could also use `@JsonSerialize(include=NON_NULL)` and simply set the other fields to null in your list view, giving you the same result.  However this is still a Jackson specific solution.

I noticed for your other two solutions, you used database centric approaches.  I'm assuming that this object is not actually in your database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think `MessageBodyWriter` isn't suited that well: I would have to write `n` implementations (or switch-case or whatever) for each content-type, one for JSON, one for XML, etc. Correct me if I'm wrong. ... A few minutes ago another crazy idea came to my head: What about annotation manipulation via reflection? I'll append an example for that to my question in a few minutes.